# Windows Batch / ADB - Check if installed .apk matches .apk from a directory

Tags: android, batch-file, adb, aapt

I am using an **FOR** command and **AAPT** command to get a package name from a number of **APKs** in a directory. I am using a separate **FOR** command and **ADB** command to list all of the 3rd party installed applications from the device.

I am unsure how to cross reference these to get the output I would like. I am trying to see if any of the contents of of the **AAPT** command appears in the the output of the **ADB** command. If the 2 variables match, do nothing. Otherwise, if the **AAPT** does not match any of the **ADB** outputs, show the package name from the **AAPT** command for that loop.

I hope you can understand what I am trying to achieve. Please see my attempt below:

```
::Global
@echo off

set AAPT=tools\aapt.exe
set GREP=tools\grep.exe
set CUT=tools\cut.exe

:: Applications
cls
@echo.
@echo ------------------------ CHECK APPLICATIONS INSTALLED --------------------------

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@echo -- EXTRACT PACKAGENAME FROM APK --
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%N IN ('adb devices') DO (
    SET IS_DEV=%%O
    if "!IS_DEV!" == "device" (
        SET SERIAL=%%N
        for /f "delims=" %%P in ('dir /b ^"APKs\*.apk^"') do (
            SET APK=%%P
            for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%Q in ('%AAPT% d badging APKs\!APK! ^| !GREP! "package: name=" ^| !CUT! -d' -f2') do (
                set package=%%Q
                if "!package!" == "" set package=Unknown (
                echo !package!
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
@echo.
@echo -- EXTRACT INSTALLED PACKAGENAME --
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%R IN ('adb devices') DO (
    if "!IS_DEV!" == "device" (
        FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%U IN ('adb shell "pm list packages -3" ^| !CUT! -f 2 -d ":"^') DO (
        SET DEVPACKAGE=%%U
        echo !DEVPACKAGE!
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
@echo.
@echo -- CHECK IF ALL "DEVPACKAGE" MATCHES "PACKAGE" AND LOOP --
for /f "delims=" %%S in ('dir /b ^"APKs\*.apk^"') do (
    if "!package:*%DEVPACKAGE%=!" neq "!package!" (
    echo !package! matched
    ) else (
    echo !package! did not match
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
@pause
```

The output I am receiving is:

```
------------------------ CHECK APPLICATIONS INSTALLED --------------------------

-- EXTRACT PACKAGENAME FROM APK --
com.microsoft.office.lync15
com.microsoft.office.officehub
com.yammer.v1
com.teslacoilsw.launcher
yes.worldpaytotal
com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.weather

-- EXTRACT INSTALLED PACKAGENAME --
com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.weather
de.worldiety.photiety.cewe.smartphoto.de
com.estrongs.android.pop
com.yammer.v1
de.zalando.mobile
com.microsoft.office.officehub
de.kaufda.android
com.microsoft.office.lync15
com.kronos.mobile.android
com.manageengine.adssp.passwordselfservice
com.teslacoilsw.launcher
yes.worldpaytotal

-- CHECK IF ALL "DEVPACKAGE" MATCHES "PACKAGE" AND LOOP --
com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.weather did not match
com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.weather did not match
com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.weather did not match
com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.weather did not match
com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.weather did not match
com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.weather did not match
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If anyone is able to help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Without having understood the whole batch, in the last section you repeatedly compare `if "!package:*%DEVPACKAGE%=!" neq "!package!"` without assigning new values to these vars but the leftover contents from the previous section.

Comment: what do you recommend? nesting it in one of the other commands?

Comment: I was just able to pinpoint a logic problem, it's up to you to decide what logic you need.