# Windows Batch / ADB - Check installed applications for multiple devices

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, adb

I am using an FOR command and AAPT command to get a package name from a number of APKs in a directory. I am using a separate FOR command and ADB command to list all of the 3rd party installed applications from the device.

I have been able to cross reference these to get the output I would like for a singular device. I am unsure how to rearrange the script to manage multiple devices as I am receiving errors.

I hope you can understand what I am trying to achieve. Please see my attempt below:

```
::Global
@echo off

set AAPT=tools\aapt.exe
set GREP=tools\grep.exe
set CUT=tools\cut.exe

:: Applications
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%N IN ('adb devices') DO (
    SET IS_DEV=%%O
    if "!IS_DEV!" == "device" (
        SET SERIAL=%%N
        for /f "delims=" %%P in ('dir /b ^"APKs\*.apk^"') do (
            SET APK=%%P
            for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%Q in ('%AAPT% d badging APKs\!APK! ^| !GREP! "package: name=" ^| !CUT! -d' -f2') do (
                set package=%%Q
                if "!package!" == "" set package=Unknown (
                echo !package!>>"%userprofile%\desktop\PCAPPS.txt"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%R IN ('adb devices') DO (
    if "!IS_DEV!" == "device" (
        FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%U IN ('adb shell "pm list packages -3" ^| !CUT! -f 2 -d ":"^') DO (
        SET DEVPACKAGE=%%U
        echo !DEVPACKAGE!>>"%userprofile%\desktop\DEVAPPS.txt"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('FINDSTR /vlxg:"%userprofile%\desktop\DEVAPPS.txt" "%userprofile%\desktop\PCAPPS.txt"') DO (
    set NOTDEVAPP=%%a
    echo !SERIAL! does not have package !NOTDEVAPP! installed
    )
del "%userprofile%\desktop\DEVAPPS.txt"
del "%userprofile%\desktop\PCAPPS.txt"
)
ENDLOCAL
@pause
```

This is related to the question: [Windows Batch / ADB - Check if installed .apk matches .apk from a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815229/windows-batch-adb-check-if-installed-apk-matches-apk-from-a-directory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch / ADB - Check if installed .apk matches .apk from a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815229/windows-batch-adb-check-if-installed-apk-matches-apk-from-a-directory)

Comment: Please see note at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 1):

The logic was incorrect. Nesting the functions works correctly.

```
::Global
@echo off

set AAPT=tools\aapt.exe
set GREP=tools\grep.exe
set CUT=tools\cut.exe

:: Applications
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

For /f "delims=" %%P in ('dir /b ^"APKs\*.apk^"') do (
    SET APK=%%P
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%Q in ('%AAPT% d badging APKs\!APK! ^| !GREP! "package: name=" ^| !CUT! -d' -f2') do (
        set package=%%Q
        if "!package!" == "" set package=Unknown (
            echo !package!>>"%userprofile%\desktop\PCAPPS.log"
        )
    )
)
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%R IN ('adb devices') DO (
    SET IS_DEV=%%S
    DEL /Q "%userprofile%\desktop\DEVAPPS.log" >nul 2>nul
    if "!IS_DEV!" == "device" (
        SET SERIAL=%%R
            FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%U IN ('adb -s !SERIAL! shell "pm list packages -3" ^| !CUT! -f 2 -d ":"^') DO (
            SET DEVPACKAGE=%%U
            echo !DEVPACKAGE!>>"%userprofile%\desktop\DEVAPPS.log"
            )
        FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('FINDSTR /vlxg:"%userprofile%\desktop\DEVAPPS.log" "%userprofile%\desktop\PCAPPS.log"') DO (
            set NOTDEVAPP=%%a
            echo !SERIAL! - package not installed - !NOTDEVAPP!>>"%userprofile%\desktop\error.log"
            echo !SERIAL! - !NOTDEVAPP! - not installed
                )
            )
        )
    )
DEL "%userprofile%\desktop\PCAPPS.log"
```